# Need to export the write output datas

Tags: powershell

I am wrote a script to get and the save the result to text file. But i cant able to save  the data to excel file. I can  able to get the what i can except. I want to save those datas to text file.

```
 $user = (Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username
$hostn = $env:COMPUTERNAME
Write-Output "$user, $hostn"
```

Output of my current script
[image]

Comment: Have a look at ```Export-Csv``` - something like ```$data = [PSCustomObject] @{ "User" = $user; "Hostname" = $hostn }``` followed by ```$data | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\myfile.csv"```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `pscustomobject`. look a the script :)

```
$user = (Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username
$hostn = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$output =[pscustomobject]@{
        'UserName' = $user
        'computername' = $hostn
    }
$output | Export-CSV c:\temp\usermanager.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
```